# CoreDataを使ったアプリ　バージョンアップで以前のデータが消えてしまいました

Tags: ios

バージョンアップ時に全データが消える(もしくは内部に保存されているが見えなくなる)という
とんでもない失態を犯してしまいました。

原因も分かりません。
バージョンアップでもデータモデルはいじっておりません。

現在、自分が考えている原因の候補としては
・本に書いてあるままに- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
の最下部に、[[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];
と書いたままにしておいたから
・マイグレーション処理をしていなかったから

の二つですが確証はありません。ググっても同じような例が見つかりませんでした。
基本的にAppDelegateはいじっておらず、候補1の処理以外は初期通りです。

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    // 略

    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
                            configuration:nil URL:storeUrl 
                            options:nil error:&error]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]; //追加
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

本当にユーザのみなさまに申し訳なくて、もしデータ復旧できるのであれば
その手段を教えていただけると助かります。

データが戻らない場合でも、次回からそうならないような対処法を教えていただけると
助かります。

Comment: [マイグレーションをしていないだけならエラーが出るようなので](http://xcatsan.blogspot.jp/2010/05/coredata_26.html)前者が気になりますが、最下部というのはreturnの直前でしょうか。前後数行を貼り付けていただくとよりわかりやすいかと思います。

Comment: @unarist

     [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];   
     NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);   
    abort();
   }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
   となっております。

Comment: コメントを参考に質問文を編集しましたが、この理解で正しいでしょうか。

Comment: @unarist 合っています。編集ありがとうございます。

Comment: どういうふうにデータを保存してるのかわかりませんが、保存先や読み込み対象のURLは相対パスで書いていますか？　アップデートでアプリごとのドキュメントフォルダへのパスが変わるので、絶対パスを使ってるとデータ読めなくなったりします。CoreDataだと関係ないのかな？

Answer (score 3):

やっと原因がわかりました。

[ここ](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/paraches/20110802/1312299545)に書いてありましたが、すべての原因はやはり
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];
の一行だったようです。
これがdata.sqlite ファイルを削除しまうので、アップデート時にデータ引き継ぎに
ならなかったようです。

みなさまご返答ありがとうございました。

Comment: エラー時にsqliteファイルを削除するようなコードなのでマイグレーションに失敗したとかで消えるのはわかりますが、モデルを変更していなくてもそうなるんでしょうか。少なくとも、データが消えない代わりにアプリが落ちるかと思います。

Comment: @unarist アプリが落ちる→再度開くと中身が消えている。という状態でした。本日adHocを使って、アップデートテストを実行してみましたが
例の一行を削除していると、バージョン前に登録したデータがそのまま表示されました。やはりこの一行が問題だったようでした。
ありがとうございました。